# Subscribe an Amazon SNS topic using AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Can we subscribe an **Amazon SNS** topic using an **AWS Lambda** function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. With help of [`sns.subscribe()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#subscribe-property)

Please keep in mind: dont forget to confirm it [`sns.confirmSubscription()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#confirmSubscription-property)

Comment: Thanks. its working. Can we set multiple end points in a single function. I am using email protocol

Comment: Sure. Just call `sns.subscribe` multiple times in your Lambda.

Comment: I am able to subscribe the topic without using sns.confirmSubscription().  Can you please let me know the purpose of this service?

Comment: For some endpoints (e.g. `email`) you need to confirm the subscription until the endpoint/subscriber gets notified. For AWS services (e.g. `Lambda`) its not the case.

Comment: I will receive an confirmation email every time the lambda is triggered, is there a way to disable the email once user confirms?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean can you use a message from a SNS topic as the [trigger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html) for a lambda function, then the answer is yes.

If you mean can you write a lambda function that adds a [subscription](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) to an SNS topic then the answer is yes. Towards the bottom are links for the language-specific AWS SDKs. Your Lambda function would need to have the appropriate permissions to be able to add a subscription as well.