# How to subscribe to a temporary db's restoration in terraform? Or it is just impossible?

Tags: terraform, boto3, amazon-sns

I am looking at [this example code](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_event_subscription.html) and I am not sure how I can adopt it to my situation:

**My Goal:**

I want to subscribe to a rds event such that my lambda function will be invoked when the data of a temporary database is completely restored from a snapshot.

**Details:**

Here is my workflow:

> 1) A lambda function `start_restore` is run at a scheduled time. This
>   function is written in python and uses `boto3` to create a temporay
>   mysql db  with names like `temp-sales-20190701`. The function will
>   find the latest db snapshot of `sales` and restore it to
>   `temp-sales-20190701`
>
> 2) Once the restoration is done, I want to perform some actions on the
>   temp db and will be dropped eventually. (*Please do not question the
>   need for a temp db in this step. I intentionally leave out a lot of
>   the details because it is very specific to the user requirement*)

Here is the code in the example:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.6.17"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name = "my_database_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.6"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "default" {
  name = "rds-events"
}

resource "aws_db_event_subscription" "default" {
  name      = "rds-event-sub"
  sns_topic = "${aws_sns_topic.default.arn}"

  source_type = "db-instance"
  source_ids  = ["${aws_db_instance.default.id}"]

  event_categories = [
    "availability",
    "deletion",
    "failover",
    "failure",
    "low storage",
    "maintenance",
    "notification",
    "read replica",
    "recovery",
    "restoration",
  ]
}
```

(As a nitpick, I think I only need `"restoration"` in the `event_categories`)

As a result `aws_db_instance.default` is not present when the terraform file is applied because `temp-sales-20190701` is created on the fly. I think it would be impossible to create a db event subscription with a unknown db id, is it right?

If so, can I create a sns subscription inside the lambda function `start_restore`?

Comment: Yes, you can create a sns subscription in code in lambda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545695/subscribe-an-amazon-sns-topic-using-aws-lambda-function

Answer (score 0):

Set source type to "db-instance"

Then only subscribe to event "restoration".

Then on the receiver side (in my case, a lambda function written in python), I filter the 'Source Id' field in the SNS topic inside the `event` parameter and look for the temp db name. If the source id matches, then the lambda function will handle the event.